# Invalid bind expression type of Opportunity for column of type String

Tags: apex, batch

Could you please help to fix I'm getting : Invalid bind expression type of Opportunity for column of type String it's showing in for loop line.

```
public class FailedFTDBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, user_uid__c FROM sf_failed_ftds__x';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> records) {
    List<Opportunity> uids = new List<Opportunity>();
    for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Account.exness_client_uid__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.exness_client_uid__c IN :records]) {
        uids.add(opp);
    }

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (Opportunity opp : records) {
        Task newTask = new Task(
            WhatId = opp.Id,
            OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
            ActivityDate = Date.today(),
            Subject = 'Failed Deposit, please check',
            Description = 'Failed'
        );
        taskList.add(newTask);
    }
    if (!taskList.isEmpty()) {
        Database.insert(taskList, false);
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

}

I've tried to pass sf_failed_ftds__x in execute method it's still showing the same error unfortunately, also once changed to sf_falied_ftds it will throw an error in the for loop : Invalid loop variable type expected sf_failed_ftds__x was Opportunity
Expected type Opportunity; found sf_failed_ftds__x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue because your start method is returning a datatype of `List< sf_failed_ftds__x>` while your execute method is expecting datatype of `List<Opportunity> records`

You can modify your Execute method to also receive the `List< sf_failed_ftds__x>` as parameter as shown below

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sf_failed_ftds__x> records) { 

     ..// Rest of your code, make sure to loop over these failed external object records and collect Account ExternalIds
  }
```